# How to use docker-credential-pass to login to a private registry?

Tags: docker, security, passwords

Docker by default saves passwords unencrypted on disk, encoded in base64. I want to securely store a login password using docker-credentials-pass keystore plugin to log in to my private registry.

https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/

I am stucked at this issue: https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/102

I've tried everything the users comment and I couldn't find any documentation for docker and pass. I google some tutorials as well without success. I restarted docker multiple times when trying and it just doesn't work. I would appreciate some help if someone knows how to set it up.

Answer (score 15):

Don't know if it's still relevant to you but this worked for us (rh7 system):

Generate a new gpg2 key with `gpg2 --gen-key` and select all the default answers (apart from name, mail and passphrase). The output you get should contain a row that looks something like this:

`pub   2048R/A154BD21 2019-09-12`

Take the part after the `/` and init your pass with `pass init <after-slash-part>`, so in this example `pass init A154BD21`.

Add the line `"credsStore":"pass"` to your `~/.docker/config.json` so that it looks something like

```
{
  "credsStore":"pass"
}
```

Make sure that the location of your `docker-credential-pass` file is in your $PATH environment variable.

Now try logging in. If it's not working, please describe a bit more in detail what you do and if you get any error messages, etc.

Comment: Yes this is good.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to achieve the same as the OP, also did some research and got stuck. I cannot login without being asked for credentials at all. Anybody else some advice?

Comment: @Robert, Do you still have the issue? I had difficulties first, but now it works like a charm.

Comment: Yes. I stopped persuing the issue at some point, but couldn't solve it until now. Any further advice?

Comment: How to configure `gopass` instead of `pass` as docker-credential-helper?

Answer (score 10):

I went with a bash script like this that automates much of the process.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Sets up a docker credential helper so docker login credentials are not stored encoded in base64 plain text.
# Uses the pass secret service as the credentials store.
# If previously logged in w/o cred helper, docker logout <registry> under each user or remove ~/.docker/config.json.

# Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

if ! [ $(id -u) = 0 ]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root"
   exit 1
fi

echo "Installing dependencies"
apt update && apt-get -y install gnupg2 pass rng-tools jq

# Check for later releases at https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases
version="v0.6.3"
archive="docker-credential-pass-$version-amd64.tar.gz"
url="https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases/download/$version/$archive"

# Download cred helper, unpack, make executable, and move it where Docker will find it.
wget $url \
    && tar -xf $archive \
    && chmod +x docker-credential-pass \
    && mv -f docker-credential-pass /usr/local/bin/

# Done with the archive
rm -f $archive

config_path=~/.docker
config_filename=$config_path/config.json

# Could assume config.json isn't there or overwrite regardless and not use jq (or sed etc.)
# echo '{ "credsStore": "pass" }' > $config_filename

if [ ! -f $config_filename ]
then
    if [ ! -d $config_path ]
    then
        mkdir -p $config_path
    fi

    # Create default docker config file if it doesn't exist (never logged in etc.). Empty is fine currently.
    cat > $config_filename <<EOL
{
}
EOL
    echo "$config_filename created with defaults"
else
    echo "$config_filename already exists"
fi

# Whether config is new or existing, read into variable for easier file redirection (cat > truncate timing)
config_json=`cat $config_filename`

if [ -z "$config_json" ]; then
    # Empty file will prevent jq from working
    $config_json="{}"
fi

# Update Docker config to set the credential store. Used sed before but messy / edge cases.
echo "$config_json" | jq --arg credsStore pass '. + {credsStore: $credsStore}' > $config_filename

# Output / verify contents
echo "$config_filename:"
cat $config_filename | jq

# Help with entropy to prevent gpg2 full key generation hang
# Feeds data from a random number generator to the kernel's random number entropy pool
rngd -r /dev/urandom

# To cleanup extras from multiple runs: gpg --delete-secret-key <key-id>; gpg --delete-key <key-id>
echo "Generating GPG key, accept defaults but consider key size to 2048, supply user info"
gpg2 --full-generate-key

echo "Adjusting permissions"
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.gnupg
sudo find ~/.gnupg -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
sudo find ~/.gnupg -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;

# List keys
gpg2 -k

key=$(gpg2 --list-secret-keys | grep uid -B 1 | head -n 1 | sed 's/^ *//g')

echo "Initializing pass with key $key"
pass init $key

echo "Enter a password to add to the secure store"
pass insert docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check

# Just a verification. Don't need to show actual password, mask it.
echo "Password verification:"
pass show docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\*/g'

echo "Docker credential password list (empty initially):"
docker-credential-pass list

echo "Done. Ready to test. Run: sudo docker login <registry>"
echo "Afterwards run: sudo docker-credential-pass list; sudo cat ~/.docker/config.json"
```

Comment: Docker now provides binary builds at https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases. The download part should look like `archive="docker-credential-pass-$version.linux-amd64"`. Then `wget $url \
    && chmod +x $archive \
    && mv -f $archive /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-pass`

Answer (score 4):

The `docker-credentials-pass` helper doesn't setup a pass-based password store - it expects an already functional password store, so I would advise you to first set that up before incorporating the credentials helper

Pass is a password manager that is essentially a bash script that automates encrypting/decrypting secrets using GnuPG. That means a working pass setup requires each of those tools to function: `pass` and `gpg2`. Optionally the password store can be a Git repository, in which case you'll need `git` installed as well.

After downloading pass and setting up GnuPG, initialize the password store with your gpg id. From the docs (assuming "ZX2C4 Password Storage Key" is your gpg id):

```bash
$ pass init "ZX2C4 Password Storage Key"
mkdir: created directory ‘/home/zx2c4/.password-store’
Password store initialized for ZX2C4 Password Storage Key.
```

You should then be able to add passwords using the `pass` command, and if that works then enable the `docker-credentials-pass` helper as you've already done.

https://www.passwordstore.org/

Comment: nicely explained. But how is `docker login` supposed to work having done `pass init` and `pass insert...`? On my end I had to enter credentials from signing up to docker hub. I am not sure `docker login` uses the gpg id/key through `pass` at all, or how it matters.